# SQL Query Count identical values and show value alongside in separate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has returns from customers and is linked to a Ticket table, which is linked with the customer Table. There is no direct relationship between the Returns table and the customer Table.

Return_Table: (columns)

```
INEDX_Return,
CustomerName, 
DateAdded
```

I would like to count the number of time the same name occurs within a Month

Expected Result:

```
Customer Name     |  No Time Name Appears
__________________|________________________
  customer 1      |  34
  customer 2      |  12
```

I wrote this, its close but the values its given me are wrong:(customer_ID is a name not a FK or int)

```
SELECT TOP 20 COUNT(Return_Table.Customer_ID) AS TimesReturned, 
       Return_Table.Customer_ID
FROM Return_Table         
WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY Return_Table.Customer_ID
```

Comment: Can you add examples of your input data in addition to the expected result.

Comment: TOP without ORDER BY doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: In what way is it wrong? Can you replicate your problem with dummy data? You need to give us more information.  We're not psychic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this.

```
SELECT CustomerName,
     COUNT(*) AS TimesReturned
FROM Return_Table         
WHERE Return_Table.DateAdded >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

Answer (score 1):

The required query needed uses a simple aggregation function. You need to count the number of instances that each name ocurres. See: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by

```
select CustomerName, count(CustomerName) from 
Return_Table 
where DateAdded between START_DATE AND END_DATE
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Luca Kiebel I think you should make a similar comment to the other answers that also do not explain the reasoning behind their code.

Comment: They haven't come up in my review queue, but if they do, I'll be sure on comment on their answers too. In the meantime you may want to set a good example and edit your answer.